# A practical real-world Java application using only immutable objects

Tags: java, immutability

There are many, many pages on the internet describing how to write an immutable class in Java. The internet has that particular subject locked down pretty tight. I'm good with that.

Regardless of the merits of the immutability principle, I have been unable to find a good Java example of how to apply this principle in a real-world situation, or falling short of that lofty goal, in a situation involving more than just the immutable object itself!

Obviously, an application in which there are no state changes is inherently useless.

As such, the immutability principle says "return a new immutable object of the same type to represent the new state of the object after its state changed". Ignoring the benefits or otherwise of this approach, the question I have is, what happens to the new object once it's been created? How can any other object hang onto it, without themselves having to change state?

**So I'm particularly interested in how constructing new immutable objects to replace old immutable objects works in practice, in Java, as a viable mechanism to handle changes in application state.**

**I don't understand how the client of the new immutable object holds onto the object without itself having to change state. That's the gap in my understanding that the question is trying to overcome.**

Here's some inspiration... how would you restructure this application to avoid mutability?

```
public class MyVideoGameApp extends Application {
    private int highScore = 0;
    public void newGame() {
        GameEngine game = new GameEngine((r) -> {
            highScore = Math.max(highScore, r.getScore());
        });
        game.start();
    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}
```

Comment: *“Obviously, an application in which there are no state changes is inherently useless.”* Try just writing a function with no state changes instead of an application, then.

Comment: Object.toString() - how does that help?

Comment: I mean a function to solve whatever real-world problem you want. If your problem is converting an object to a string, voilà, your `toString` implementation probably doesn’t mutate anything and solves a problem.

Comment: See, this is the problem with not specific enough questions like this. It's very vague what could constitute an acceptable answer, @AlexandarPetrov's answer is a good example on this. I would recommend you go and modify your question, maybe creating a pet example program and ask people how would they do that in Java in the _most_ functional way possible (note that Java is not a _pure_ functional programming language, so a _pure_ functional solution might not be possible). The question is good, just the way it's formulated is too broad in my opinion.

Comment: Hopefully I've addressed the vagueness of the question with the code example.

Comment: Once again, mutability is not something you avoid in an entire application. Some tasks are well-suited to FP, some aren’t.

Comment: Wow. This is going very badly. Let's see if I can clarify the question further.

Comment: @Ryan can you illuminate further on which tasks are well-suited to FP, and which aren't? What criteria do you apply to determine suitability?

Comment: Your video game is a function from a game state and a user input to a new game state. That can be implemented in Java with an immutable object representing the game state. Whether it’s useful to do so is up to use of judgement.

Comment: @user2754486: Please cut it out with the smarm. All your example program does is keep track of a high score, which is already a close enough Java equivalent of what I was describing (the entire game state is a high score, and `int`s are immutable).

Answer (score 0):

Hello I will try to give you a real life example. Lets suppose that we have a bank and account. We have also transactions that are running across the account.  Lets now say that this transactions are happening for a day and the day needs to be closed and all transactions reflected upon the account.

The transaction sequence will change the state of the Account and the balance and some times it will result in charges that will in addition affect the balance. If the balance go below a limit, the account may enter Blocked state. After each transaction your account will enter a unique state. This state is different from its original state.

By having all the states of the account you can theoreticaly rewind to a previous state at any time in case of a faulty transaction.

Here is metacode example of the above . The metacode is very generic , but such is the question.

```
class Account {
    // can be blocked account, Debit, Credit
    ACCOUNT_TYPE state;   

    public Account applyTransaction(Transaction transaction) {
      // returns new Account with transaction applied
    }

}

class TransactionProcessingJob {

 public processTransactions(List<Transaction> transactions,Account accountToProcess) {


   List<Account> allAccountStates =  transactions.stream().map(t->accountToProcess.processTransaction(t)).collect();

  Account lastState = allAccountStates.getLast();

  // do whatever you want to do.
  //rewind if you want
 }

}
```

Based on last edit, not sure what you want to achieve but here is a modification improving imutability:

```
  public class MyVideoGameApp extends Application {


    public void newGame() {
        Score allTimeHighScore = Normaly it is durable somewhere;  
        Game game = () -> {
                            Random rand = new Random();
                            return Score.scoreOf(rand.nextInt());   
                            };
        GameEngine gameengine = new GameEngine(game);
        Score finalScore = gameengine.play();

        writeToDurableLocation (Score.max(allTimeHighScore, finalScore);

    }
    public static void main(String args[]) {
        launch(args);
    }
}

   @FunctionalInterface
public interface Game {

    public Score play();

}

        public class Score {

            private final int score;

            private Score(int score) {
                this.score = score;
            }

            public static Score scoreOf(int score) {
                return new Score(score);
            }

            public boolean equals(Score score) {
                return this.score == score.score;
            }


            public static Score max(Score scoreLeft, Score scoreRight) {
                return scoreLeft.score >= scoreRight.score ? scoreLeft : scoreRight;    
            }

        }
```

Comment: Thanks, but that's a theoretical answer. And I was after a practical one.

Comment: @user2754486 this is a real life example. Not theoretical at all.

Comment: @user2754486 what kind of example do you expect ? Maybe I don't understand.

Comment: One using the Java programming language, and more than one class / type of object.

Comment: @user2754486 If you want more detailed than this read https://vaughnvernon.co/?p=838

Comment: Hopefully I've addressed the vagueness of the question with the code example.

Comment: Alexandar, your solution is not equivalent to the example. Your example seems to be determining the higher score out of two users playing a single game instance.

In my example, the logic is attempting to keep track of the highest score across the range of single game instances. Think of space invaders. I might have a game. You might come along three hours later. One of us will have the higher score. The {highScore} attribute in my example is intended to track this state. Your example does not do that.

Comment: @user2754486  No offence but your example is unclear in terms of what your goal is. You have a new game and some new score that is completly unclear on what it is based and what the logic is. If yuo have a game the outcome of the game is completly independent on any outside factors for the game. Sory but fix your semantic first. What your goal is , what your game is ? and so on...

Comment: Alex, the example is 13 lines of code. In what possible way are you confused?

Comment: @user2754486  What is the score what is the game ? Why the game would has any dependency on this highscore outside the game and what is this highscore. Be more specific.

Comment: @user2754486 why would you want to keep track of the highest score ? What's the point ?

Comment: @user2754486  you need to follow the single responsibiliy princile and you are breaking it. You game has the responsibiliy to produce Score or result. The responsibility if this score is highest of some amount of games do not fall within the game itself.

Comment: @user2754486 First you ned to define your entities and their responsibilities. Your main involved parties are - GameEngine, Game, Score. It is responsibility of the Game to produce result. It is not responsibility of the game to say if a score is highest or not. The score is clear what it is. It is responsibility of the GAmeEngine to tell if this score is highest of all games played. Got it ?

Comment: @user2754486  sory I actualy meant the GameApp GameEngine, Game and Score. The responsibility to manage the all  time highest score is the APP.